# PowerShell's Invoke-WebRequest not working within a Docker Container

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-container, invoke-webrequest

In my dockerfile I have a line `RUN PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File /approot/bin/DockerScripts/reqs.ps1`

Within reqs.ps1 there is an invoke-webrequest command like so, `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://path/to/exe/ExeNeeded.exe -OutFile C:\ExeNeeded.exe`

When I run `docker build` on my computer I get an error on the `RUN PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File /approot/bin/DockerScripts/reqs.ps1` step

The error is:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote name could not be resolved:
https://path/to/exe/ExeNeeded.exe
At C:\approot\bin\DockerScripts\reqs.ps1:5 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://path/to/exe/ExeNeeded.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I am able to access `https://path/to/exe/ExeNeeded.exe` through my web browser, so I know the url is good. I also temporarily turned off the firewall on my computer. I'm not sure why `Invoke-WebRequest` is still not working.

Comment: Make sure your URL is in quotes and try to use the parameter `-SkipCertificateCheck`

Comment: Where should I put the `-SkipCertificateCheck`? In the Dockerfile or in my reqs.ps1 script? Should I set `-SkipCertificateCheck` to true? I tried both and the quotes and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Okay, my bad. This parameter only works in Powershell 6.0 or higher (parameter would be after the `Invoke-Webrequest`. Can you give me the url you try to reach? Did you test `google.com` or some other well known site?

Comment: Using google.com returns the same error

Comment: This might be a issue of docker, I found this Github issue:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6453

Comment: Adding `--network "Default Switch` to the build command did not work either

Comment: So I'm using Service Fabric to package my application. I think I need to the dns within the docker container. But I am not sure how to do with while using Service Fabric

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, but that's where I can't help you anymore. I am not very experienced with docker. :( I hope someone else can help you

Answer (score 2):

It is known [issue#6453](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6453) for windows users. Add **network** parameter when building the image.

```
docker build -t myProject . --network "Default Switch"
```